# Problem constructing and appendNode function ifor a linked llist C

Tags: c, function, linked-list, append, nodes

[source code from tbaMUD](https://github.com/tbamud/tbamud)

In **file "handler.c"**, we have this **"obj_to_room"** function, which takes any object dropped in the room and adds it to a linked list. This creates a stack of objects, with the first object at the bottom (head) of the stack, the second object stacked on top the first, and so on. This is the default behavior for linked lists in C.

In **file "act.informative.c"** we have the **"look_at_room"** function. That calls the **"list_obj_to_char"** function. This uses a **"for loop"** to read the list/stack.

When using a "for loop" to read the list/stack/node, it does so from top (tail) to bottom (head). This, too is the default behavior in C. Therefore, objects dropped in the room are displayed with the most recently dropped object at the top of the list and the first object dropped at the bottom.

That's what causes this issue:
[www.tbamud.com/forum/2-general/5530-has-anyone-else-noticed](https://www.tbamud.com/forum/2-general/5530-has-anyone-else-noticed)

My goal is to invert the order of objects in that linked list. There are a few hacks I might pull off, but that's just what they would be - hacks, not exactly proper and certainly not elegant. I think the best solution is coding a function using **"appendNode"** to add objects at the tail (top) of the list instead of its head (bottom).

Toward that end, I need to change this:

```
    /* put an object in a room */
void obj_to_room(struct obj_data *object, room_rnum room)
{
  if (!object || room == NOWHERE || room > top_of_world)
    log("SYSERR: Illegal value(s) passed to obj_to_room. (Room #%d/%d, obj %p)",
    room, top_of_world, (void *)object);
  else {
    object->next_content = world[room].contents;
    world[room].contents = object;
    IN_ROOM(object) = room;
    object->carried_by = NULL;
    if (ROOM_FLAGGED(room, ROOM_HOUSE))
      SET_BIT_AR(ROOM_FLAGS(room), ROOM_HOUSE_CRASH);
  }
}
```

to something like this:

```
/*put an object in a room */
void obj_to_room(struct obj_data *object, room_rnum room)
 {
    if (!object || room == NOWHERE || room > top_of_world)
    {
      log("SYSERR: Illegal value(s) passed to obj_to_room. (Room #%d/%d, obj %p)",
        room, top_of_world, (void*) object);
    }
    else
    {
      /*function to add objects at the tail of the list instead of its head*/
      /*everything hinges on this single line and I probably have it all kinds of wrong*/
      /*struct node* appendNode(struct node** head, int key)*/
      struct world[room].contents* appendNode(struct world[room].contents** object, room_rnum room)
      {
           /* special case for length 0*/ 
        if (object == NULL)
        {
          *object = world[room].contents;
        }
        else
        {
         /* locate the last node */
          while (object->next_content != NULL)
          {
            object = object->next_content;
          }
          object->next_content = world[room].contents;
          world[room].contents = object;
          IN_ROOM(object) = room;
          object->carried_by = NULL;
          if (ROOM_FLAGGED(room, ROOM_HOUSE))
            SET_BIT_AR(ROOM_FLAGS(room), ROOM_HOUSE_CRASH);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Problem 1

Although I'm familiar with multiple programming languages, C is not one of them. When it comes to the idiosyncrasies and technical fine points of the language, I know nothing. That makes reading C code challenging and writing it even more so.

Problem2

I understand the format should be:

```
struct node* appendNode(struct node** head, int key)
```

I think the **head** and **int key** are correct, but I'm unable to identify the node in the original code. So I used my best guess.

It's not surprising that attempting to compile this code yields:

```
handler.c: In function ‘obj_to_room’:
handler.c:681:19: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘[’ token
  681 |       struct world[room].contents* appendNode(struct world[room].contents** object, room_rnum room)
      |                   ^
make[1]: *** [<builtin>: handler.o] Error 1
```

Ok, I suspect there's all sorts of things wrong with that line, but I don't know how to fix it. I'm hoping that some brilliant coder will be kind enough to help out.

Comment: You could start with the fact that standard C doesn't support nested functions, even in the case where they're not even called (which yours is *not*). And you're correct, `truct world[room].contents** object` is complete nonsense in any formal parameter list declaration, no matter what the context.

Comment: Wow, don't I feel stupid! Have it figured out now. Much appreciation.

Answer (score -1):

This does the trick.

```
/* put an object in a room */
void obj_to_room(struct obj_data* object, room_rnum room)
{
  if (!object || room == NOWHERE || room > top_of_world) {
    log("SYSERR: Illegal value(s) passed to obj_to_room. (Room #%d/%d, obj %p)", room, top_of_world, (void *)object);
  }
  else {
    if (world[room].contents == NULL) {  // here, we have an empty list.
      world[room].contents = object; // Just add it.
    }
    else {
      struct obj_data* i = world[room].contents; // define a temporary pointer
      while (i->next_content != NULL) {
        i = i->next_content; // find the first without a next_content
      }
      i->next_content = object; // add it at the end
    }
    object->next_content = NULL; // end of the linked list
    IN_ROOM(object) = room;
    object->carried_by = NULL;
    if (ROOM_FLAGGED(room, ROOM_HOUSE)) {
      SET_BIT_AR(ROOM_FLAGS(room), ROOM_HOUSE_CRASH);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A strong answer will explain what the problem was and how this resolves it. as an editor has noted `// mostly for sanity. should do nothing.` is incorrect.